# how to define jsdoc properties inside an object using @memberof instead of @property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsdoc, jsdoc3

how to define properties inside an object using maybe @memberof or @alias instead of using @property and defining each property outside the object. i have something like:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {


    /**
    * @alias Foo#state
    * @property {array} countryList counrty list
    */
    this.initialState = {

      /** 
      * @type {boolean}
      */
      active: true,

      /**
      * @type {number[]}
      * index of items in viewport
      */
      visibleItems: null,

      countryList: [],
      // ...
    };
  }    
}
```

the initialState could get really long and i prefer to add jsdoc to each item instead of copiing everything and putting before the definition.
For this example, jsdoc generates only the `countryList` as a property of Foo.state.
I tried these two options and they didn't work.

```
/**
* @type {number[]}
* @alias Foo#state.visibleItems
*/
visibleItems: null

/**
* @type {number[]}
* @memberof Foo#state
*/
visibleItems: null
```